# EXPO errors and warnings when using vector icons

Tags: react-native, expo

I've recently updated my Expo SDK from 3.0 to 3.2 and I've suddenly started to get all kinds of erros, at first I needed to replace my use of vector icons from

`import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";`

to

`import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';`

Because I started to get the following error using the old method 
`fontFamily "Ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.`

I checked the expo docs https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

It is the recommended method. But now when using this method I get the following message

`The syntax "import { Font } from 'expo-font'" is deprecated. Use "import * as Font from 'expo-font'" or import named exports instead. Support for the old syntax will be removed in SDK 33.`

So I'm confused as it is recommended to use this method in version 3.2 but it will be also deprecated in the next

I've tried changing my `.babelrc` file

```
{ 
    "presets": [ "babel-preset-expo" ] 
}
// Uitgeschakeld inverband met https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2576
// {
//   "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
//   "env": {
//     "development": {
//       "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Removing `node_modules` and reinstalling

checking expo version in app.json and package.json

App.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Rapio",
    "description": "Wait less, enjoy more.",
    "slug": "Rapio",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.rapio.consumerapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.rapio.consumerapp"
    },
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "navigation": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-payment-gateway": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to use the correct method for using icons without getting error messages or warnings